# about ListView nested ListView, how to get the outer ListView item position

Tags: android

I want to delete the inner `listview`'s item, but I don't know the outer `listview`'s item position, because I want to delete through it. How do I do this?
[image]

Comment: you shouldn't nest ListView. Use ExpandableListView instead.

Comment: thanks，i try first,If there are any problems, I will ask you again.

Comment: Thank you for you help me，thanks again：）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ExpandableListView instead of nested Listview. Using ExpandableListView you will get id.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I try first, and then, the problems, to consult you again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) you will get a example.

But if you want to do as you have done now[should avoid this], Save your outer list (item) id in your inner list adapter model. After that on item click of inner listview (delete) you will get the id of outer list item.

But you should go with ExpandableListView.

Comment: thanks，I use ExpandableListView, completed the task，and thanks again。